# SP 2013 - Custom List, Send Email Workflow to People and Groups not working

Tags: 2013, workflow, email, person

I have created a Custom List which has a 'Person or Group' Column which is used to denote the Item Owner.

When the List Item is changed I want to send a notification to the Item Owner.

I have built a List Workflow in SPD 2013, the workflow passes checks but when I edit a list item I receive no email, the workflow status is updated as completed.

I receive emails from built-in SP functions, but don't seem to be able to hit the right config for this Workflow.

[image: Workflow Config]

[image: Email Recipient Config]

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working with the if modified by feature, you could work off the built-in modified column in SharePoint.  This column is automatically populated by SharePoint whenever a change is made.  When that column is populated/changed an email could be sent like you are attempting.

[image]